# Multiple UpdatePanel postback trigger updateprogress animation of other UpdatePanel

Tags: asp.net, webforms, updatepanel, updatepanel-progressbar

I have multiple `UpdatePanels` on a webpage, one inside UserControl (Purple ColorBox as show in image) and other inside the main page. When the paging user-control `(< 1 2 3 >)` of Main page is invoked it shows the corresponding  `UpdateProgress` of 'Latest News' Section but also shows the `UpdatePanelAnimationExtender` of 'Subscribe' User-control.

I am using `UpdatePanelAnimationExtender` for user-control and `UpdateProgress` for the Latest-New which is on the main page.

I tried to change the properties but it keeps on coming; if I keep `UpdateMode="Conditional"` for user control then progress bar goes in loop and show continuously.

**Screen Shot**[image: Update Panel]

How can I make changes to this code to show only corresponding progress bar. I have looked over 50 example from last few days but nun seems to be working. I would appreciate if someone can help me to get this fixed.

```
 <!-- LatestNewArea -->
    <div class="LatestNewArea">
        <asp:UpdatePanel ID="updLatestNews" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional">
        <ContentTemplate>
            <asp:Repeater ID="rptLatestNews" runat="server" EnableViewState="False" onitemdatabound="rptLatestNews_ItemDataBound">
                <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:HyperLink ID="hylLatestNews" CssClass="chylLatestNews" runat="server" NavigateUrl=''>
                    <div class="LatestNewsWrapper">
                        <div class="LatestNewsDateBox">
                            <div class="LNYYYY">
                                <asp:Label ID="lblYYYY" runat="server" Text="2012"></asp:Label>  
                            </div>
                            <div class="LNDDMM">
                                <asp:Label ID="lblDDMM" runat="server" Text="12/08"></asp:Label> 
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="LatestNewsTitle">
                            <asp:Label ID="lblLatestNewsTitle" runat="server" Text="First News for the Website"></asp:Label>
                        </div>
                        <div class="LatestNewsHDate">
                            <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="Hijri: 15 Rajab 1433"></asp:Label>
                        </div>
                        <div class="LatestNewsDesc">
                            <asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server" Text=""></asp:Label>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="LNHLine"> </div>
                </asp:HyperLink>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:Repeater>
        <!-- Pager -->
        <div class="LatestNewsPagerWrapper">
        <div class="LatestNewsPagerInnerWrapper">
            <asp:UpdateProgress ID="UpdateProgress1" runat="server" DisplayAfter="50" AssociatedUpdatePanelID="updLatestNews" >
                <ProgressTemplate>
                <div id="imgLoadingArticleList" class="imgLoadingArticleList">
                    <asp:Image ID="imgLoading" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/images/ajax-loader-bar2.gif"  />
                </div>
                </ProgressTemplate>
            </asp:UpdateProgress>
            <uc1:PagerControl ID="PagerControl1" runat="server"  CssClass="gold-pager"  PageMode="LinkButton"  />
        </div>
        </div>
        <!-- Pager -->
    </ContentTemplate>
    </asp:UpdatePanel>
    </div>
    <!-- LatestNewArea -->
```

**User Control Page Code**

```
    <script type="text/javascript">

        function onUpdating() {
            // get the divImage
            var panelProg = $get('divImage');
            // set it to visible
            panelProg.style.display = '';

            // hide label if visible      
            var lbl = $get('<%= this.pnlSubscribe.ClientID %>');
            lbl.innerHTML = '';
        }

        function onUpdated() {
            // get the divImage
            var panelProg = $get('divImage');
            // set it to invisible
            panelProg.style.display = 'none';
        }

    </script>

<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="SubscribeContainer">
    <tr>
        <td align="center">
            <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="SubscribeWrapper" border="0">
                <tr>
                    <td valign="top">
                    <asp:UpdatePanel ID="updSubscribe" runat="server" >
                        <ContentTemplate>  
                                <asp:Panel ID="pnlSubscribe" runat="server" Height="10px">
                                    <div class="SubHeading"><asp:Label ID="lblTitle" runat="server" Text="JOIN US"></asp:Label></div>
                                    <div class="dSubName">
                                        <asp:TextBox ID="txtName" CssClass="txtSubscribe" runat="server" Text="NAME" onfocus="if(this.value=='NAME')this.value='';" onblur="if(this.value=='')this.value='NAME';"></asp:TextBox>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="dSubEmail">
                                        <asp:TextBox ID="txtEmail" CssClass="txtSubscribe" runat="server" Text="YOUR EMAIL" onfocus="if(this.value=='YOUR EMAIL')this.value='';" onblur="if(this.value=='')this.value='YOUR EMAIL';"></asp:TextBox>
                                        <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="rfvEmailSub"  runat="server" ErrorMessage="*" 
                                            ControlToValidate="txtEmail" ValidationGroup="SubEmail" ></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                                        <asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="revEmailSub" runat="server" 
                                            ErrorMessage="*" ControlToValidate="txtEmail" ValidationExpression="\w+([-+.']\w+)*@\w+([-.]\w+)*\.\w+([-.]\w+)*" 
                                            ValidationGroup="SubEmail" ></asp:RegularExpressionValidator>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="dSubSubmit">
                                        <asp:Button ID="btnSubscribe" CssClass="btnSubscribe" runat="server" ValidationGroup="SubEmail" Text="Subscribe" onclick="btnSubscribe_Click" />
                                    </div> 
                                </asp:Panel> 
                                    <div class="dSubMSG"> 
                                    <asp:Label ID="lblMSG" runat="server" Text=""></asp:Label>
                                </div>
                                            <div id="divImage" style="display:none" class="dSubAni">
                                                <asp:Image ID="Image1" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/Images/loader-sub.png" Visible="true"/>
                                            </div>

                        </ContentTemplate>
                    </asp:UpdatePanel>

                    <asp:UpdatePanelAnimationExtender ID="UpdatePanelAnimationExtender1"  TargetControlID="updSubscribe" runat="server">
                    <Animations>
                        <OnUpdating>
                            <Parallel duration="0">
                                <ScriptAction Script="onUpdating();" />

                                <EnableAction AnimationTarget="btnSubscribe" Enabled="false" />                    
                            </Parallel>
                        </OnUpdating>
                        <OnUpdated>
                            <Parallel duration="0">
                                <ScriptAction Script="onUpdated();" /> 
                                <EnableAction AnimationTarget="btnSubscribe" Enabled="true" />
                            </Parallel>
                        </OnUpdated>
                    </Animations>
                    </asp:UpdatePanelAnimationExtender>  


                       </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
```

Other Info: ASP.Net 4.0, C# & Paging control is a user control that uses linkbutton for paging

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried many solution but non of them worked in a proper way. Finally i decided to replace `UpdatePanelAnimationExtender`  of user control with `UpdateProgress` as I was able to trap the initiating UpdatePanel for `AsyPostback`

For some reason i was not able to trap `AsyPostback` when i used `UpdatePanelAnimationExtender`

This approach can be used for multiple update panel one need to trap the initiating control for post-back

**BELOW IS A WORKING CODE**

```
    // Function to hide control on update
            function onUpdateOfSubscribe() {
                var panelProg = $get('divImage');
                // set it to visible
                panelProg.style.display = '';
                // hide label if visible      
                var lbl = $get('<%= this.pnlSubscribe.ClientID %>');
                lbl.innerHTML = '';
            }
    //Code to track the initiating event so to associate updateprogress
        var currentPostBackElement;
        function pageLoad() {
            var manager = Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance();
            manager.add_initializeRequest(OnInitializeRequest);
        }
        //On OnInitializeRequest
        function OnInitializeRequest(sender, args) {
            var manager = Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance();
            currentPostBackElement = args.get_postBackElement().parentElement;

            var cmdAuthoriseButton = '<%= btnSubscribe.ClientID %>';
            if (cmdAuthoriseButton == args._postBackElement.id) {
                // Show UpdateProgress for subscribe 
                onUpdateOfSubscribe();
            }
        }
    </script>

<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="SubscribeContainer">
        <tr>
            <td align="center">
                <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="SubscribeWrapper" border="0" >
                    <tr>
                        <td valign="top">
                        <asp:UpdatePanel ID="updSubscribe" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional"   >
                            <ContentTemplate>  
                                    <asp:Panel ID="pnlSubscribe" runat="server" Height="10px">
                                        <div class="SubHeading"><asp:Label ID="lblTitle" runat="server" Text="JOIN US"></asp:Label></div>
                                        <div class="dSubName">
                                            <asp:TextBox ID="txtName" CssClass="txtSubscribe" runat="server" Text="NAME" onfocus="if(this.value=='NAME')this.value='';" onblur="if(this.value=='')this.value='NAME';"></asp:TextBox>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="dSubEmail">
                                            <asp:TextBox ID="txtEmail" CssClass="txtSubscribe" runat="server" Text="YOUR EMAIL" onfocus="if(this.value=='YOUR EMAIL')this.value='';" onblur="if(this.value=='')this.value='YOUR EMAIL';"></asp:TextBox>
                                            <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="rfvEmailSub"  runat="server" ErrorMessage="*" 
                                                ControlToValidate="txtEmail" ValidationGroup="SubEmail" ></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                                            <asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="revEmailSub" runat="server" 
                                                ErrorMessage="*" ControlToValidate="txtEmail" ValidationExpression="\w+([-+.']\w+)*@\w+([-.]\w+)*\.\w+([-.]\w+)*" 
                                                ValidationGroup="SubEmail" ></asp:RegularExpressionValidator>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="dSubSubmit">
                                            <asp:Button ID="btnSubscribe" CssClass="btnSubscribe" runat="server" ValidationGroup="SubEmail" Text="Subscribe" onclick="btnSubscribe_Click" />
                                        </div> 
                                    </asp:Panel> 
                                        <div class="dSubMSG"> 
                                        <asp:Label ID="lblMSG" runat="server" Text=""></asp:Label>
                                    </div>
                                                <div id="divImage" style="display:none" class="dSubAni">
                                                    <asp:Image ID="Image1" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/Images/loader-sub.png" Visible="true"/>
                                                </div>

                            </ContentTemplate>
                            <Triggers>
                                <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="btnSubscribe" EventName="Click" />
                            </Triggers>
                        </asp:UpdatePanel>
                    <asp:UpdateProgress ID="UpdateProgress1" runat="server" AssociatedUpdatePanelID="updSubscribe" >
                        <ProgressTemplate>

                        </ProgressTemplate>
                    </asp:UpdateProgress>


                           </td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
```